# Find most recent result in query - ms access

Tags: date, ms-access

I have an access database, for which I am trying to determine the most recent result in a query. I want to know whether the most recent loan for any item is complete or not. e.g.

tbl_Loans

```
LoanID    Equipment Number  Start Date  Return Date Expr:IsOnLoan
123       78457             16/05/2001  19/06/2003  Loan Complete
124       79557             17/07/2016              Loan in Progress
125       78457             03/06/2016              Loan in Progress
126       79630             01/01/2015  01/01/2016  Loan Complete
127       79360             02/03/2016              Loan in Progress
128       78457             01/01/2016  01/03/2016  Loan Complete
```

Where Expr:IsOnLoan is an IIF:

```
IsOnLoan: IIf([Loans]![Return Date] Is Null,"Loan Active","Loan Complete")
```

I would like to return the most recent result for each equipment number in another column in a query (probably a separate query) i.e.

```
Loan ID    Equipment Number   Start Date  Return Date Expr:IsOnLoan
125        78457              03/06/2016              Loan in Progress
127        79360              02/03/2016              Loan in Progress
128        78457              01/01/2016  01/03/2016  Loan Complete
```

Microsoft's support pages would have me use a 'top' but others I've seen have used an inner join and I can't get either of them to work.

Any help greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this is to use an `INNER JOIN` between your `tbl_Loans` table and a subquery which identifies the most recent dates for each equipment number.

```
SELECT t1.LoanID,
       t1.[Equipment Number],
       t1.[Start Date],
       t1.[Return Date],
       t1.[Expr:IsOnLoan]
FROM tbl_Loans AS t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT [Equipment Number], MAX([Start Date]) AS [Start Date]
    FROM tbl_Loans
    GROUP BY [Equipment Number]
) AS t2
    ON t1.[Equipment Number] = t2.[Equipment Number] AND
       t1.[Start Date] = t2.[Start Date]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've been trying to use this for the last couple of days and I can't seem to get it to work. I get a couple of errors:  The first was 'circular reference caused by alias 'Start Date' in query definition's select list.  I tried to alter this by changing 'AS [Start Date] to MaxStart. However then I get an error 'You have written a subquery that can return more than one field without using EXISTS reserved word in the main queries FROM clause. Revise the select statement of the subquery to return only one result. I am a bit clueless as to how to resolve this.

Comment: Sorry, was editing post after hitting enter! To be clear new code is now 'Expr1: (SELECT t1.LoanID,  t1.[Equipment Number],        t1.[Start Date],        t1.[Return Date],        t1.[Expr:IsOnLoan] FROM tbl_Loans AS t1 INNER JOIN (     SELECT [Equipment Number], MAX([Start Date]) AS [MaxStart]     FROM tbl_Loans     GROUP BY [Equipment Number] ) AS t2     ON t1.[Equipment Number] = t2.[Equipment Number] AND        t1.[Start Date] = t2.[MaxStart])  Apologies for formatting